# Protractor can not find any elements yet elements render in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

Has anyone come across a scenario where your protractor script can not find ANY OF ELEMENTS (count == 0) yet the elements are rendering in the browser? I am testing a section of our site that was recently changed and now the tests are failing. When I use "elementor" or other debugging tools, it says no elements found for all the elements on the page. Yet the page is rendering correctly.

When I inspect using elementor I see:

```
[by.css('section[ng-controller="app.DatepickerController as vm"]'): “0”
```

where `0` is the count.

And:

```
[by.css('section.panel-body'): "12"
```

where `12` is the count for the same element.

Below is a sample of the HTML. It is supposed to display a "Datepicker".

```
<section class="panel-body ng-scope" ng-controller="app.DatepickerController as vm">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<h3>Datepicker</h3>
<div td-datepicker="" show-ignore-year="vm.showIgnoreYear" show-all-before="vm.showAllBefore" all-before="vm.allBefore" show-all-after="vm.showAllAfter" all-after="vm.allAfter" ignore-year="vm.ignoreYear" date="vm.date" disabled="vm.dateIsDisabled" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<div class="td-datepicker" ng-class="{ open: vm.open, invalid: !vm.isValid &amp;&amp; vm.hasOpened &amp;&amp; !vm.open }">
<div class="input-group"><div class="td-datepicker-value" ng-click="vm.toggle()" ng-disabled="vm.   disabled" ng-class="vm.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''">
<span class="td-datepicker-value-month ng-binding" ng-class="{ active: vm.open &amp;&amp; vm.mode === 'month' }">MM</span>/
<span class="td-datepicker-value-day ng-binding" ng-class="{ active: vm.open &amp;&amp; vm.mode === 'day' }">DD</span>/
<span class="td-datepicker-value-year ng-binding" ng-class="{ active: vm.open &amp;&amp; vm.mode === 'year' }">YYYY</span>
</div>
<div ng-class="{ 'active': vm.open, 'disabled': vm.disabled}" class="input-group-addon" ng-click="vm.toggle()" ng-disabled="vm .disabled"><i class="md md-today"></i>
</div>
```

```
<div ng-show="vm.open" class="td-datepicker-popover ng-hide">
```

Month
Day
Year

------Controller
(function () {

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('app.DatepickerController', appDatepickerController);

function appDatepickerController() {
    /*jshint validthis:true */
    var vm = this;
    // Disable functionality from controller
    // Using Date Picker as example
    vm.dateIsDisabled = true;

    // Date picker
    vm.date = undefined;
    vm.showIgnoreYear = true;
    vm.showAllBefore = false;
    vm.allBefore = false;
    vm.showAllAfter = true;
    vm.allAfter = true;
    vm.showIgnoreYear = false;
    vm.ignoreYear = false;

    // Year picker
    vm.year = undefined;

    // Month picker
    vm.myear = undefined;
    vm.mmonth = undefined;

    // Quarter picker
    vm.qyear = undefined;
    vm.qquarter = undefined;

    // Week picker
    vm.wyear = undefined;
    vm.wweek = undefined;
}
```

})();

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML code of the block?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my posting now

Comment: Also adding the corresponding controller for this section of code...

Comment: This was resolved after convincing the developer that it was a coding issue..and not a browser issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved after convincing the developer that it was a coding issue..and not a browser issue.